# transfer data between two mnesia tables

Tags: erlang

I have two table counter and count

```
   -record(counter, {key, value}).
    -record(count, {key, value}).


    create() ->
        mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
        mnesia:start(),
        mnesia:create_table(counter, [{attributes, record_info(fields, counter)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
        mnesia:create_table(count, [{attributes, record_info(fields, count)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),



    mnesia:stop().
```

but when I try to run this function

```
backup()->

    mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
  Records = mnesia:select(counter, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),
  [ok = mnesia:write(count, Record, write) || Record <- Records]
end).
```

I have this error

```
2> model:backup().
{aborted,{bad_type,{counter,test,353}}}
```

when I use your code :

```
mnesia:create_table(count, [{record_name, counter}, {attributes, record_info(fields, counter)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]).
```

and when I try to run model:reset() it deletes the table count and the data of table counter

my goal is juste to delete the data of counter

this is the code of reset()

```
reset() ->
    stop(),
    destroy(),
    create(),
    start(),

    {ok}.


destroy() ->
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:delete_table(counter),
    mnesia:delete_table(person),
    mnesia:stop(),
    mnesia:delete_schema([node()]).


create() ->
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table(counter, [{attributes, record_info(fields, counter)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
    mnesia:create_table(person, [{attributes, record_info(fields, person)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
  mnesia:create_table(person_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]),
    mnesia:stop().
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write counter record in count table which is resulting in error. There are two ways to do this.

1. Either use a single record called counter and use in for count table also as
   mnesia:create_table(count, [**{record_name, counter}**, {attributes, record_info(fields, counter)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]).
2. If above is not possible if you have other fields, you can copy the required elements from counter record to count record before writing.